# Delete or edit my own question?

Tags: support, edits, questions

Assume I have asked a poor question. Also assume that the question can become good with editing and without changing the meaning of the question.

- Is deleting it and creating a new question ever a good alternative?
- If it is, when should I choose which alternative and why?
- Is down votes on current question something that can be considered?
- Assuming the question is unanswered, what would be bad with creating a new instead of editing?

My own thoughts are these:

- I cannot see any harm in deleting and recreating an unanswered question, unless someone is currently writing an answer.
- Close votes ages away after a while, so they are nothing to care about.
- If the question has a long list of comments suggesting improvements, it's easy to flag them as "no longer needed" when the question is corrected.
- When it comes to down votes, although they should indicate that the question shows "no research, is not useful or is unclear" we all know that that is unfortunately not always the case. Furthermore, they don't age away and they do in general only represent the quality of the question when the vote was cast.

Answer (score 5):

> Is deleting it and creating a new question ever a good alternative?

No, you should not be doing this. Whenever possible, fix the question up rather than deleting and recreating. If you've asked a bad question and it hasn't yet been answered, then by all means, feel free to self-delete it. But don't reask it exactly how it was before.

> If it is, when should I choose which alternative and why?

As I said previously, you should not delete and reask your questions. You should instead be editing them into shape so they are good, on-topic questions. However, you should *not* completely change the meaning of your question through edits.

> Is down votes on current question something that can be considered?

Downvotes simply indicate the number of users who though your question was badly-researched or otherwise not useful. *Do not* delete your question because it was downvoted. Edit it. Edits bump the question to the homepage where it can be upvoted and downvotes can be retracted if the downvoters view the question again. Also, if the question was closed, edits relatively soon after the question was closed (I'm not sure of the exact numbers) push the question into Reopen Votes where users can vote to reopen or leave closed.

If the question's simply not a good fit for the site and can't be edited to become on-topic without completely changing the meaning, then that's okay. Sometimes edits just aren't enough to fix something without changing the whole meaning (which, by the way, you should not do through edits). Learn why it was off-topic and avoid asking things like it in the future.

> Assuming the question is unanswered, what would be bad with creating a new instead of editing?

There's nothing wrong with this, as long as you ask a different question. As mentioned before, you should not self-delete and repost the exact same question. If you wish to self-delete while the question's unanswered and you want to ask something *different*, that's fine.

I would also encourage you to not self-delete if there's nothing *wrong* with your current question. Even if no answers were posted yet, there could certainly be one or more users in the process of writing an answer to the question. It's really frustrating when a question is self-deleted for no good reason while you're answering it, and also a little unfair to the author of the not-yet-posted answer.

Answer (score 4):

The best time to sort out whether a question is good or bad is *before* you post it.

Editing is always better *if* you can make edits that don't change its substance (that's to say *never ever edit* a question into a completely different question). It's generally better than deletion simply because people see you made the effort.

*Once* edited, in theory users can undo their downvotes (though they'd need to know said question was downvoted by them and "better") or folks would upvote it. Upvotes have a *significantly* larger impact than downvotes in terms of reputation.

Self deletion is *rarely* an optimal option unless its seriously poor or off topic. It's fine to defer it to the community.